# Get max value on arithmethic overflow

Tags: c#, integer-overflow, arithmetic-expressions, integer-arithmetic, overflowexception

Is there a built-in way to get max value on arithmetic overflow?

Here's what I need:

```
var val = byte.MaxValue + 1;

//should be rounded down to byte.MaxValue
MyByteProperty = val;
```

P.S. I know I can do that by wrapping it as a `checked` expression as [Alex answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29188165/75500), my question is if there's a built-in way in the language or BCL.

Comment: I think you're looking for what's called a "saturated add".

Comment: What you're looking for is called *saturation arithmetics*, and is afaik not available for built-in types and operators, because that would conflict with how programmers expect these to behave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are `checked` and `unchecked` keywords, that indicate whether exception will be thrown if overflow occures:

```
try
{
    MyByteProperty = checked(byte.MaxValue + 1);
}
catch (System.OverflowException e)
{
    MyByteProperty = byte.MaxValue;
}
```

Comment: I'm aware to that. My question was if there is a built-in way for doing that.

Comment: Isn't this built-in enough?

Comment: @PatrickHofman For one, this construct is arguably much more verbose than e.g. `MyByteProperty = val > byte.MaxValue ? byte.MaxValue : val`, but even that you have to manually put around every assignment/calculation, as opposed to something built-in (which I believe does not exist).